# Error: Invalid hook call. function using hooks been called inside a list in class

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MaterialUI. I have my Dashboard that has a list of Cards. My Dash is a class that extends `React.Component`. My Cards are a function that is using Hooks `useState`. My dash is using `.map()` to build the list of cards. My cards have a function to "show data".

Dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Service from '../app/Service';
import Copyright from '../components/Copyright'
import CardContact from '../components/CardContact'



const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    paddingTop: '80px'
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },

});




class Dashboard extends React.Component {
 state ={

 }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.contactsFormatted();
  }



  contactsFormatted = async () => {
    try {
     const res = await Service.get('/all-contacts');
     const contacts = res.data;

     this.setState({
       Contacts: contacts.map((contact, i) => (
         CardContact(contact, i)
       ))
     })
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }


  render(){
  const { classes } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {this.state.Contacts}
          </Grid>

          <Copyright />
        </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
}



export default withStyles(styles)(Dashboard);
```

My CardContact.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';

const CardContact = ({name, office, occupation_area, tel, email}, i) => {

    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const handleExpandClick = () => {
      setExpanded(!expanded);
    }

    return (
      <Grid xs={12} style={{ paddingBottom: 32 }} key={i} item={true}>
      <Card >
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">  
            Nome: {name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography  color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
            Cargo: {office}
          </Typography>
          <Typography  color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
            Área de atuação: {occupation_area}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>



        <CardActions style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}} >
          <Button  size="small" 
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}>Revelar</Button>
        </CardActions>

        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography  color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
            Telefone: {tel}
          </Typography>
          <Typography  color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
            E-mail: {email}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
      </Card>
      </Grid>
    )
  }

  export default CardContact;
```

what's wrong with the Hooks usage?

Comment: I guess it is wrong with the mapping algorithm. Try to map with `jsx` with `key` prop passed to every card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `CardContact` inside `contactsFormatted` method. Hence React is throwing the error as `contactsFormatted` is not a valid React component. React components with hooks should only be invoked/rendered from a valid render function of a React component (class or functional).

Try this :

```
contactsFormatted = async () => {
    try {
     const res = await Service.get('/all-contacts');
     const contacts = res.data;

     this.setState({contacts})
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

And in render :

```
render(){
  const { classes } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {this.state.contacts.map((contact, i) => (
              <CardContact contact={contact} index={i} />
            )}
          </Grid>

          <Copyright />
        </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now the full data will be available in `CardContact` component as `contact` prop

Comment: what can I do to solve? is there some way to construct the list differently?

Comment: Invert the data flow. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by an earlier answer, this is not the right approach, to render cards. Instead of storing the components in the Contacts state, you should store the objects corresponding to the cards in the Contacts state, like this:

```
    contactsFormatted = async () => {
    try {
     const res = await Service.get('/all-contacts');
     const contacts = res.data;

     this.setState({
       Contacts: [...Contacts].concat(contacts),
     })
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

Further, you should render the cards as below:

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {(this.state.Contacts || []).map((contact, i) => <CardContact contact={contact} i={i} />)}
          </Grid>

          <Copyright />
        </Container>
    </div>
  );
```